# Preventing concurrency violations in Access DB without access to the queries or code

Tags: ms-access

I have a legacy vb.net application that I'm trying to fix, the application stores data in a Microsoft Access database (mdb) file in the `c:\programdata` folder.

The application has started giving the following error when it's writing to this database:

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

As I have no access to the application code or to the queries it is running to the access database, are there any changes I can make, either to the database or the environment to minimise or prevent this error?

**edit - some more information:**

The application connects to and syncs with a MySQL database, the change that has triggered this error to start appearing was this MySQL database being moved to a new provider.

I have successfully decompiled the application executable and I can now access the queries that the application is running against the MySQL database however it seems to use TableAdapters with the access database to do all the updates.

Here is the configuration of the new MySQL instance:

https://pastebin.com/CgA4Cpa2

Comment: That folder isn't really intended for this purpose. Try moving the database file to the user's `%localappdata%` folder.

Comment: The application's name is a secret;) Maybe someone around knows it. As it worked porperly in past, when does it start to fail? Try a moving to a former enviroment (OS, CPU, Drivers, etc) that worked. You tried to decompile the code (e.g ILSpy).

Comment: @Gustav The path to this file is hard coded into the application making moving it very difficult

Comment: @ComputerVersteher It is a bespoke library application used by a handful of charities in the UK, it's unlikely that anyone would be familiar with it. The application is used to synchronise a remote MySQL database and an MS Access database (with the Access DB as the master), the MySQL environment has recently been transferred to another platform (with no possibility of transferring back) which seems to have caused the issue.

Comment: Moving a hard-coded path isn't difficult if you know [hard-links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). You changed MySQL Version (maybe config file is different, can you show them)? Why is moving back imposible (e.g. virtual machine)? Tried decompile? Add the additional infos to your question!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I can get the config of the new MySQL version however the old server and environment is now offline and the hosting company is out of business. I will add the config to the question

Comment: No backup, no mercy :(  Can you provide the old MySQL version number? Your error is offten caused by rounding issues (e.g. on single-float datatype) that leads JET (ms access db engine ) to think the data has been changed. Can you create an ODBC logfile (in ODBC-Datasources)?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher The old MySQL version appears to be `5.5.58-cll` (from the MySQL dump file). The application uses an OleDB connector so I don't think this can be intercepted?

Comment: Which connector and what is the programming language of the app? Some things changed from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6m espacally timestamps, see docs. Can you show a failling query and the tables stucture? Can you downgrade on MySQL 5.5?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher it uses Devart MySql connector version 6.8, as far as I can tell it was written in vb.net (.net 2.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174835/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-bendataclear).

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the application code, you can do very, very little.

A technique you can try using, if you have insight into what exactly the application is doing, is renaming the table causing the conflict, and then create a query with the same name as your table previously had and the *Record Locks* property set to *No Locks* that just selects everything from that table. However, depending on what the application is doing (normal queries using OLEDB is fine, direct access to the tables using ADOX or DAO is not), that might break the application altogether.

Anyway, any solution is going to be hacky as long as you can't fix the real problem (the application code causing the concurrency conflicts).